# How to determine brightness/contrast of a SurfaceView in android?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview, brightness

Im a noob to android development and i want to make a simple camera application that automatically turns on the torch light if the lighting is very dark.  I have read through [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) for a camera method that would allow me to get a lightness/darkness value from the camera, but have been able to find one.  I am using a surfaceview to display my camera.  Is there some possible way to get a brightness or contrast value from the view in real time?  any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that this may have been what you read about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738294/android-detect-brightness-amount-of-light-in-phones-surroundings-using-the-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you need to access the light sensor.  Look at [this tutorial](http://androidshivendra.blogspot.com/2013/12/android-light-sensor-example.html) and it should point you in the right direction