# Card.IO camera flash for Android

Tags: android, card.io

In the card.io SDK for iOS, the flash will automatically on in the low-light situation. Why this approach not implement in Android SDK? Is it possible to do the same thing in Android SDK as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a native Android camera doing so. Usually the flash is activated by the user. In spite of it most Android phones have light detector, so you may implement such behavior yourself with a similar code - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4739048/3657198