# Android : Is there a way to detect a change in brightness of an android device.

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I am designing a game in which the player has to change the brightness of his phone in order to pass to the next level.

The idea I have is that there might be an android-permission to allow detect a change in the brightness level.

So my question is that how do I use it in my app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46119780/1671672

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4739048/7385033

Comment: Just an aside-  you may have problems with anyone who has autoadjust on.  Which is the default I think.  Unless you're requiring a massive change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if screen brightness has changed in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119279/how-to-detect-if-screen-brightness-has-changed-in-android)